# Limit of a difficult sequence

Tags: limits, analysis

I stucked in one part of my task where i have to find a limit of given sequence. I have absolutely no idea how to even start solving this problem. Any hints?

$$a_n = \sqrt[n]{4^{2n} - 5^{n+2} - \sin(\sqrt{n})}  $$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Looks like $16$

Comment: A cat is bigger than a mouse, and a man is bigger yet, and a truck is bigger still. You know that right away, without using a ruler. Same thing here. Which of the terms under the root is "bigger" than the rest?

Comment: Heuristically, think about ignoring the n-th root for a moment and think about each of the terms separately as $n$ gets large. Do they all grow at the same rate? Try plotting them using a graphing calculator like Desmos and see if that gives you any intuition.

Comment: One of the 3 terms grows biggest. Divide and multiply by that term under the radical. And then take the multiplier outside the radical. Now examine what's happening with the stuff left under the radical. You can take the limit.

Comment: I can't believe that i didn't see that before. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{4^{2n} - 5^{n+2} - \sin(\sqrt{n})}$$
as pointed out by @Ivan Neretin in the comments:
$$\sqrt[n]{4^{2n} - 5^{n+2} - \sin(\sqrt{n})}\approx\sqrt[n]{4^{2n} - 5^{n+2}}$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}\exp(\frac{\ln(4^{2n} - 5^{n+2})}{n})=\exp(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(4^{2n} - 5^{n+2})}{n})$$
$$= \exp(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2\ln(4)4^{2n} - \ln(5)5^{n+2}}{4^{2n} - 5^{n+2}})$$
notice that the the $5^{n+2}$ terms grow considerably smaller in proportion as n increases, this is due to the smaller exponent, therefore we can approximate both th top and bottom by eliminating the $5^{n+2}$ term:
$$= \exp(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2\ln(4)4^{2n}}{4^{2n}})$$
$$= \exp(\lim_{n \to \infty}2\ln(4))$$
$$= \exp(2\ln(4)= 16$$

Comment: This seems way more complicated than necessary. It'd be easier to note that $$a_n=\sqrt[n]{4^{2n}-5^{n+2}-\sin\sqrt n}=16\sqrt[n]{1-25\left(5\over16\right)^n-{\sin\sqrt n\over16^n}}\to16\sqrt[n]{1-0-0}=16$$

Comment: tbh @Barry Cipra I wrote the first half of the post and then I realized this but I was already committed so :(.

Comment: Been there, done that! You can always do a complete rewrite. Ping me if you do and I'll delete my comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, @BarryCipra I will be gone for the next few hours, so I won't be able to write it right now. Go ahead and post an answer if you wish as it does seem interesting.

Comment: @AmeetSharma, oh, you're right, I shouldn't have left the $n$ root in the limited expression. I should've just said $16\cdot1$.